# ExpandableListView: More than one list item's onclick methods executing for a single click event

Tags: java, android

I am working with an ExpandableListView. I have buttons on the child list element, which on clicking changes the background colour of list element. The problem encountered:
**More than one list element undergoes execution across different list headers.**

Adapter:

```
public class DashHomeAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private ArrayList<OrderHeader> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<OrderHeader, ArrayList<FoodItem>> _listDataChild;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query;
HashMap<Integer, String> map;

public DashHomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrderHeader> listDataHeader,
                       HashMap<OrderHeader, ArrayList<FoodItem>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    map = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final FoodItem child = (FoodItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_order, null);
        ChildViewHolder viewHolder = new ChildViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ChildViewHolder viewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(child.getName());
    viewHolder.priceTextView.setText(child.getPrice());
    viewHolder.quantityTextView.setText("x" + Integer.toString(child.getCount()));
    viewHolder.commentsTextView.setText(child.getComments());
    map.put(childPosition, "Inititalized");

    viewHolder.acceptOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (map.get(childPosition).equals("Initialized")) {
                final ProgressDialog pgDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
                pgDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                pgDialog.show();
                query = ParseQuery.getQuery(child.getId());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                        pgDialog.hide();
                        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

                            String refId = objects.get(i).getString("ID");
                            if (refId.equals(child.getOrderId())) {
                                objects.get(i).put("Status", "Order Accepted");
                                objects.get(i).saveInBackground();
                                viewHolder.childCardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                viewHolder.acceptOrderButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                viewHolder.rejectOrderButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                viewHolder.serveOrderButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.rejectOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (map.get(childPosition).equals("Initialized")) {
                final ProgressDialog pgDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
                pgDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                pgDialog.show();
                query = ParseQuery.getQuery(child.getId());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                        pgDialog.hide();
                        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

                            String refId = objects.get(i).getString("ID");
                            if (refId.equals(child.getOrderId())) {
                                objects.get(i).put("Status", "Order Rejected");
                                objects.get(i).saveInBackground();
                                viewHolder.childCardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                viewHolder.acceptOrderButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                viewHolder.rejectOrderButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.serveOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (map.get(childPosition).equals("Initialized")) {
                final ProgressDialog pgDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
                pgDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                pgDialog.show();
                query = ParseQuery.getQuery(child.getId());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                        pgDialog.hide();
                        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

                            String refId = objects.get(i).getString("ID");
                            if (refId.equals(child.getOrderId())) {
                                objects.get(i).put("Status", "Order Done");
                                objects.get(i).saveInBackground();
                                viewHolder.childCardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                                viewHolder.serveOrderButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ChildViewHolder {

    TextView nameTextView;
    TextView priceTextView;
    TextView quantityTextView;
    TextView commentsTextView;
    AppCompatButton rejectOrderButton;
    AppCompatButton acceptOrderButton;
    AppCompatButton serveOrderButton;
    CardView childCardView;

    public ChildViewHolder(View view) {
        nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        priceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
        quantityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantityTextView);
        commentsTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.commentsTextView);
        acceptOrderButton = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.acceptOrderButton);
        rejectOrderButton = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rejectOrderButton);
        serveOrderButton = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.serveOrderButton);
        childCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.childCardView);
    }
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final OrderHeader headerTitle = (OrderHeader) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_order, null);

        ParentViewHolder viewHolder = new ParentViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ParentViewHolder viewHolder = (ParentViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    viewHolder.userNameTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    viewHolder.userNameTextView.setText("Username: " + headerTitle.getUsername());
    viewHolder.dateTimeStampTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    viewHolder.dateTimeStampTextView.setText(headerTitle.getDateTimeStamp());
    viewHolder.orderNumberTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    viewHolder.orderNumberTextView.setText("OrderNo: " + headerTitle.getOrderNo());

    return convertView;
}

static class ParentViewHolder {
    TextView userNameTextView;
    TextView dateTimeStampTextView;
    TextView orderNumberTextView;

    public ParentViewHolder(View view) {
        userNameTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.usernameTextView);
        dateTimeStampTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.dateTimeStampTextView);
        orderNumberTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.orderNumberTextView);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

I even tried to implement the accepted solution from another similar question by using HashMap, but it did not work. Thanks in advance.